# Advice in Understanding this Key generating Algorith for Blowfish Algorithm

Tags: matlab, encryption, blowfish

The code is for MATLAB and i want to understand what exactly they are trying to do. I m new to matlab so need some advice. Please Help

```
function [key] = keyGen(n)
n = n*8;
% n = 2048*2048*16;
% n = 24 * 24 * 8;
bin_x = zeros(n,1,'uint8');
r = 3.9999998;
bin_x_N_Minus_1 =  0.300001;
x_N = 0;
tic

for ind = 2 : n
     x_N = 1 - 2* bin_x_N_Minus_1 * bin_x_N_Minus_1;    
      if (x_N > 0.0)
         bin_x(ind-1) = 1;
      end 
        bin_x_N_Minus_1 =  x_N;

      end
toc
%save bin_sec bin_x;
t = uint8(0);
key = zeros(n/8,1,'uint8');
for ind1 = 1 : n/8

    for ind2 = 1 : 8
    key(ind1) = key(ind1) + bin_x(ind2*ind1)* 2 ^ (ind2-1);
    end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameter `n` is the number of bytes in the key. `n*8` is to convert that into a number of bits. `bin_x` is used to store the binary representation of the key. bin_x_N_Minus_1 is the value which we use to calculate the next bit.

In the first for loop, we loop through the bits in the key (the first bit is always a 0). We calculate x_N using that formula (bin_x_N_Minus_1 is the previous value of x_N). If x_N is positive, the corresponding bit in the key is 1, otherwise it is a zero.

`tic` and `toc` are used to time how long this for loop takes.

The second for loop converts the bits of the key into bytes, and stores them in output array, `key`. The Kth entry in `key` is the 8 bit number represented by taking every (N/8)th entry in bin_x, starting from K.

The variables `r` and `t` are unused.